# Shortcut for accessing object attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a `model` object with a property called `definition` that i am using across a class. I can access that property like `model.attributes.definition`

Every time that i want to use this property inside a method, and for the sake of clarity, i am creating a shortcut `definition = model.attributes.definition` at the very beggining so the method code does not get populated with boilerplate.

Because i am using it across several methods i thought that, instead of creating the shortcut on every method, i could create a little helper function to do the job:

```
getDefinition: (model) ->
  model.attributes.definition
```

and then use it anywhere like

```
if getDefinition(model).name?
  doSomething()
```

But aren't these function calls across my code innecessary/resource consuming for such a trivial task? What is a good approach in a situation like this?

Comment: If performance your only concern? Then forget it, you're worrying about nothing, those performance concerns are more applicable elsewhere (most likely not where you think they are).

Comment: Ideally any helper shortcuts would be on the class rather than a function taking an object - see the pattern forming? (e.g. a method on your model object). This would keep it object-oriented, but does add complexity to your code. As it appears to be a simple model, I would not factor out a function to access that member. Not all simple repeated code should be factored out :)

Comment: @delnan: clarity is my concern at this point but not at the cost of performance

Comment: @HiTech Magic: well i suppose you are right. Anyway, when the same line is repeating, say 6-10 times in a class, the spidey-sense tells me that is time to do some refactor.

Comment: Have you actually performed timing analysis/profiling so you know how much extra time the function call takes? Hint: it's almost nothing. That said, if you're using classes, it seems more like a mixin or class method.

Comment: I agree with @delnan and @Dave; Code first, optimize later. If you really want to improve your code, then according to the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), the helper method belongs on your model object (assuming you have access to it).

Comment: Whoops, I just realized @HiTechMagic just said the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access object values via string:

```
definition = "attributes.definition"
```

then to access the value:

```
if model[definition].name?
    doSomething()
```